# StackOverflowError by using Wordpress 4.0 on Quercus

Tags: java, php, wordpress, tomcat, wildfly-8

i want to use Wordpress on an applicationserver (Tomcat or JBoss, doesn't matter what version) with Quercus.

Installation and configuration with the mysql database works fine. 
But when i create a new article or a new page the view of the frontend crash and it shows a StackOverflowError.

```
com.caucho.quercus.QuercusModuleException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
   com.caucho.quercus.QuercusModuleException.create(QuercusModuleException.java:64)
   com.caucho.quercus.module.StaticFunction.invoke(StaticFunction.java:128)
   com.caucho.quercus.env.JavaInvoker.callJavaMethod(JavaInvoker.java:814)
   com.caucho.quercus.env.JavaInvoker.callMethod(JavaInvoker.java:690)
   com.caucho.quercus.env.JavaInvoker.call(JavaInvoker.java:671)
   com.caucho.quercus.expr.CallExpr.evalImpl(CallExpr.java:229)
   com.caucho.quercus.expr.CallExpr.eval(CallExpr.java:141)
   com.caucho.quercus.expr.Expr.evalTop(Expr.java:538)
   com.caucho.quercus.statement.ExprStatement.execute(ExprStatement.java:67)
   com.caucho.quercus.statement.BlockStatement.execute(BlockStatement.java:105)
   com.caucho.quercus.program.Function.callImpl(Function.java:420)
   com.caucho.quercus.program.Function.callMethod(Function.java:456)
```

...

I use:

Wordpress 4.0

Apache Tomcat 8.09 / WildFly 8.1.0 Final

JDK 1.8.0.05

Quercus 4.0.39

mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar

Why does that StackOverflowError appear and what can i do to run Wordpress stable on an applicationserver?

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question for anyone to help you on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information you have provided, I can think of two possible explanations:

1. The thread stack might be too small.  Unfortunately, I can't tell you *which* thread stack is too small.
2. Something might be causing Quercus to go into a recursion loop.  Unfortunately, I cannot tell you where or why that is happening.

I know that is unlikely to be any use to you, but unless you provide a full stacktrace, source code and other *relevant* information, that's about all that can be deduced.

Comment: Thanks, i increase the JBoss JAVA_OPTS to -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m but that's no enough for Wordpress 4.0 but Wordpress 3.8 runs fine.